# Release Notes and features of different SSRS versions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anyone know of where future features of SSRS are listed?

This article [SQL Server 2008 R2 November CTP – What’s New In Reporting Services?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104152837/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2009/11/09/sql-server-2008-r2-november-ctp-what-s-new-in-reporting-services.aspx) from the SQL Server Reporting Services Team Blog lists some of the features that are released with SS2K8 R2

However, I'm curious if they have a full list of release notes and features for each version of SSRS.

Comment: what kind of features are your "angry users" missing or asking for? I'm just seriously getting into SSRS - so if I can avoid common pitfalls, I would love to know ahead of time ;-)

Comment: This is a good article: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr4

I list the two I want - vertical merging and horizontal tables. We make heavy use of them here.

Answer (score 1):

No future feature list for SSRS exists other than what is known about R2; the engine underwent a major overhaul in 2005 so I would not expect significant new features until the vNext.Next - that said if you look at some of the momentum in various areas you might get an idea of what to expect. New mapping related functionality, more interactive reporting (maybe a silverlight play), more robust export options and finer grained control over data processing.

What features do you need? They may already be implemented by a third party or they could be something you could create a CRI for...

Answer (score 1):

**SSRS 2016 is a fantastic update to a solid product. [New in 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/what-s-new-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs)**

You may also consider leveraging **[Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/)**, PowerPivot (free) to connect Excel directly to SQL Server, or Analysis Cubes
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at home in this topic but maybe this does what you need: [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Report Builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dbddc9b6-6e19-4d4b-9309-13f62901b0d5&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at new [features of SSRS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx) here